# Timestamp Updating Constantly on /dev/null

Tags: unix

I've been working on a problem with a /dev/null file on an AIX system (just for background it looks as though it was inadvertently deleted and recreated as a normal file  by somebody), but in trying to determine what caused the problem, I noticed that the timestamp on it seems to update every minute. I've observed this on several AIX servers at my workplace.

At present I can't entirely rule out this be something specific to the Application being used at my workplace, so I compared with CentOS and Debian based computers at home last night.

The CentOS box, which runs 24 hours, had a mod time on /dev/null of around 4 days ago (during which time it was essentially just being used as a web browser and multimedia player, although it would have had active but essentially unused Apache, MySQL and VMM processes running in the background).

The timestamp on /dev/null on the Debian machine, which was a just booted laptop, pretty much reflected the boot time, but I tested redirecting STDIN from, and STDOUT to it, and the modification time was unchanged (I'm not sure 100% sure if directing data to /dev/null constitutes "writing to it" in the way it would a normal file).

So my question is essentially, could anybody please offer any advice with regards to what circumstances (permissions changes etc.. aside) might cause the timestamp on /dev/null to update?

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Alex.

Comment: Does AIX have an audit system that you can enable and use to get a log of what/who is changing the file when ?

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is essentially, could anybody please offer any advice with regards to what circumstances (permissions changes etc.. aside) might cause the timestamp on /dev/null to update?

On most systems I'm familiar with, exactly the same circumstances that would cause the timestamp on any file to update: Creation (updates `ctime`), Access (updates `atime`), or Modification (updates `mtime`).

- **Creation** should only happen once, when the device node is created.
- **Access**  should really only happen in conjunction with Modification in this case(nobody is going to READ `/dev/null`....)
- **Modification** happens every time someone pipes output to `/dev/null`.

I've no idea why your Debian system doesn't behave this way (though I've verified that the Ubuntu machine on my desk doesn't update the times on `/dev/null` when I send output there, so it's almost certainly a Linux/Debian thing related to their implementation of devfs).

Your AIX systems should faithfully update times on devices when they're accessed - including `/dev/null`. BSD (FreeBSD 9.x) behaves similarly, and I believe Solaris does as well but I don't have a Solaris box to test on.

---

The bigger question you should be asking is "**What idiot deleted `/dev/null`?!**" so you can find them and make an example out of them (and obviously if you haven't already you should remove the regular-file `/dev/null` and recreate the proper device node. A reboot is probably also in order since some programs may be holding the regular-file `/dev/null` inode open and still writing to it...).